# Run Regex in Sublime || Make Regex Package in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Is it possible to run a regex snippet in Sublime text. Either by using a keyboard bind, or by creating a package?

The expression is

```
^\s*$
```

And it removes all double RETURNs/Lines in a document. Very handy for the OCD in me.

Any help, hints, tips or suggestions on this are more than welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit `Ctrl+H`, for 'replace', this brings up a box at the bottom of the screen, click the `.*` button, enter `^\s*$`, and it'll find all double enters, and you can replace them with whatever.

or there is a plugin that looks pretty powerful that should also allow you to do this called [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is actually what I already do and I'm trying to avoid. Just a process that automates this entirely would be nice. Can it be done in the sublime-keymap?

Comment: @user1166885 - Did you try using the RegReplace plugin, that I link to above? It looks as though it should let you do this...